# Calling an Ajax-enabled WCF Application from AutoCompleteExtender

Tags: ajax, wcf, ajaxcontroltoolkit, autocompleteextender

I'm trying to use a WCF service to fulfill MS Ajax AutoCompleteExtender completion list. I tried two alternatives. If I add a WCF service in my website project, AutoCompleteExtender calls it thriugh POST and it works fine.

Then I decided to make a separate WCF Application and add my AJAX-enabled WCF service to new application. I also copied part of `Web.config` of my site concerning `servicemodel`. And it doesn't work! First of all, autocomplete calls a service uing `GET`, not `POST`. I changed `WebInvokeAttribute` and `WebGet` of my service to accept `GET`. Now the service sends a correct response to extender (I watched this using Fiddler) but extender doesn't fill completion list.

The extender is defined as follows (`act` is a tag for AjaxControlToolkit):

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" autocomplete = "off"></asp:TextBox>
    <act:AutoCompleteExtender ID="TextBox1_AutoCompleteExtender" runat="server" 
        DelimiterCharacters="" Enabled="True" ServiceMethod="GetNames" 
        ServicePath="http://localhost:4227/Service1.svc" TargetControlID="TextBox1">
    </act:AutoCompleteExtender>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1"
        runat="server" Text="Button" />
</div>
 <act:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</act:ToolkitScriptManager>
</form>
```

WCF service works on port 4227. It is running by Visual Studio. In the first case ServicePath is `Service1.svc`.

Web.Config defines sevicemodel in a such way:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <services>
        <service name="WcfService1.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="WcfService1.Service1Behavior">
            <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="WcfService1.Service1AspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.Service1" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="WcfService1.Service1AspNetAjaxBehavior">
                <enableWebScript/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="WcfService1.Service1Behavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

So, I have two auestions:

1. Why in this cases Autocomplete uses different verbs to send a request?
2. Why it doesn't work in the second case?

I uploaded a [sample solution](http://pustovoytov.ru/WCF_AJAX_Autocomplete.zip) to reproduce problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why it doesn't work in the second
>   case?

AutoCompleteExtender uses AJAX to fetch data. Cross domain AJAX requests are not allowed. Your web service is hosted on `localhost:4227` and your web application is hosted on `localhost:XXXX` where `XXXX` is different than 4227.

More info on [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: Do you mean that `example.com:xx` and `example.com:yy` are different domains? And domains `example.com` and `test.example.com` are also different?

Comment: The `Same Origin Policy` imposes that **protocol**, **second-level domain** and **port** number of the request URI be the same to grant access from one resource to another. More info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: Ok, thank you. Could you give advice how I can call from AJAX my webservice? I want it to be deployed not as part of website project and to use it (if hosted under IIS) in other aplication pool then website.

Comment: What would you advise to choose: deploy WCF Service as application in Website (in this case I need to add reference to website assembly?) or use port sharing?

Comment: I would advice you to create a bridge which is create an ASP.NET generic handler (.ashx) that will be part of the web site and that will perform the call to the actual web service. Then the `AutoCompleteExtender` could use this generic handler to fetch the data.